# Is WSE2 obsolete?

Tags: .net, design-patterns, .net-2.0, web-services-enhancements

I'm attempting to bring some .net 1.1 legacy code into .net 2.0 and some of it relies on the Microsoft.web.services2 web services enhancements.

I could have swore I read somewhere about the objects in that dll being packaged into the .net 2.0 framework, or that they were replaced by something else in the .net 2.0 framework, but I'm not having much luck finding evidence to support that.

What sayeth the collective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WSE 2.0 was meant for use with .NET Framework 1.1 (as stated on the [WSE 2.0 MSDN download page](http://www.microsoft.com/DownLoads/details.aspx?FamilyID=fc5f06c5-821f-41d3-a4fe-6c7b56423841&displaylang=en)).  [WSE 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=018a09fd-3a74-43c5-8ec1-8d789091255d&displaylang=en) is based on the .NET 2.0 runtime, which might be what you're thinking of.

Neither one comes standard with the framework, as they are both add-ons.